# Groovy Cannot cast object RowLitigeLivraison@e0bc67a with class RowLitigeLivraison to RowLitigeLivraison

Tags: grails, groovy, bonita

I tried to resolve this problem with groovy script. I had the exception:

> Groovy script throws an exception of type class `org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException` with message:
>   Cannot cast object 'org.bonitasoft.mbricolage.mrbricolibrary.objects.RowLitigeLivraison@3daae7cd' with class 'org.bonitasoft.mbricolage.mrbricolibrary.objects.RowLitigeLivraison' to class 'org.bonitasoft.mbricolage.mrbricolibrary.objects.RowLitigeLivraison'

When i try to execute this code :

```
Dossier dossier1 = dossierDAO.findByNumero(dossier.getNumero());
        ArrayList<LigneLitige> lignes = new ArrayList<LigneLitige>();
        if (formResultObj.getContext().getChoix() == "1"){

            for (RowLitigeLivraison ligneDeLitige : formResultObj.getLitigeLivraison().getList()){
                if (ligneDeLitige.getReserves() > 0){
                    LigneLitige litige = new LigneLitige();
                    litige.setCodeAmpf(ligneDeLitige.getAmpf());
                    litige.setGenCode(ligneDeLitige.getGencode());
    }}}
```

Where `formResultObj.getLitigeLivraison().getList()` returns a `RowLitigeLivraison` list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That could happen sometimes if you get two version of the Jar that contains this class. By example, if you have it deployed in the application web and as a dependency of the process.

Is that the case here?

Cheers